# Format number of seconds as interval HH:MM:SS in Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Im working with quantities of times represented as an absolute number of seconds in my data pipeline. It's fairly trivial do something like

```
select 42602 * interval '1 second';
```

which return `11:50:02` the proper answer.

However when i run the same logic on actual data

```
select on_call, 
    on_call::int * interval '1 second'
from dev_isaac.agency_time_report
order by agent_name, day_of;
```

The resulting interval column instead populates as
[image]

Why is there a difference in how redshift handles this and is there a good way around this without just manually calculating each piece.

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51454950/redshift-conversion-of-string-field-in-hhmmss-format-to-seconds-and-backwards

Comment: Fix the formatting on your output, please.

Comment: It looks like it is converting the interval into milliseconds? It might be a result of how your SQL client is converting the value. Perhaps cast it as a time?

Answer (score 0):

A bit convoluted... but this could work for HH:MM conversion:

```
(DATEDIFF(second,'2011-12-31 8:30:00','2011-12-31 20:30:15')/(60*60))::VARCHAR || ':' || MOD(DATEDIFF(second,'2011-12-31 8:30:00','2011-12-31 20:30:15'),(60*60))
```

Here is the solution we landed on:

```
LTRIM(DATEADD(seconds,DATEDIFF(seconds,order_create,placed_time),'1900-01-01 00:00:00'),'1900-01-01')::time
```

Comment: This is supposed to work: TO_CHAR(("ga:AvgSessionDuration" || ' second')::interval, 'HH24:MI:SS'), however getting the following error: 

Function "to_char(interval,text)" not supported.

Query 1 ERROR: ERROR:  Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.

Comment: It seems like Redshift doesn't want to enable passing of concatenated variables into the to_char function...

Comment: Here is the solution we landed on:

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, if you are sure that the call time will never be greater than 24 hrs, you can use a rather simple method.

Something like this,

```
select split_part((current_date+(on_call||'seconds')::interval)::varchar),' ',2)
```

This will add the number of seconds to the current date and splits it based on the space.